# Clipboard cut long paths c#

Tags: c#, winforms, path, clipboard, pathtoolongexception

i'm trying to paste whatsapp desktop attachments to my C# windows forms app.

I select the files in whatsapp and press ctrl + C. Then, i go to my windows forms app and press ctrl + V.
The process works correctly, but fails when the file names are too long. If file path is longer than 260 chars, the Clipboard.GetFileDropList() method cut it to 260, so i cannot get the file. If i paste it into a windows folder, it works correctly. (i cannot change the whatsapp temp folder)

i've enabled the registry key, group policy and i've created the app manifiest, but it not works
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry

I also tried longPathAware and UseLegacyPathHandling, but not works...

I cannot use UNC escape path because the clipboard gives me the paths.

any idea?